# Retrieve image stored in Oracle database as lob through PHP

Tags: php, image, oracle, image-processing, lob

I have to show an image which is stored in `Oracle` database as `OCI-Lob` Object.

I have used following code:

```
if(oci_fetch_array($rssqlclass,OCI_ASSOC | OCI_RETURN_LOBS)) {
  $a = oci_result($rssqlclass,"image");
}
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream;');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename='.$_GET['name']);

print $a->load();
```

I have found above code with some research on Google. But those seems to be not working. What should I do to extract image stored in Oracle Database through `PHP`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are you getting errors? What's the exact output?

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056287/oracle-blob-as-img-src-in-php-page

Comment: @Mat There are no errors. It displays null. Nothing change.

Comment: @castt : I did went through that post and tried everything that has explained there but it gives "The webpage not found error". I just don't understand why its not working?? Can anyone please help. Please please............

Answer (score 2):

Actually my problem has been solved. I am posting here the solution so that anyone else facing same problem would take benefit from it.

```
$sql="select photo from tblphoto where id='$id'  ";
$query= oci_parse($connect, $sql);
oci_execute($query); 
$showrow = oci_fetch_row($query);
if(!$showrow){
return;
}else{
$image=$showrow['0']->load();
header("Content-type: image/JPEG");
print $image;
}
```

I hope it would help someone, someday. BTW thanks everyone for commenting. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using OCI_RETURN_LOBS, you should already have the BLOB in $a at line 3. You are not fetching the returned array, try this code:

```
if($res = oci_fetch_array($rssqlclass,OCI_ASSOC | OCI_RETURN_LOBS)) {
  $a = $res['image'];
}
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream;');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename='.$_GET['name']);

print $a;
```

Comment: Its giving error as "The image cannot be displayed because it contains error". But the image is fine in db.

Comment: please look at the value printed from $a without using your image headers

Comment: `if(oci_fetch_array($rssqlclass,OCI_ASSOC | OCI_RETURN_LOBS))
 {
 $a=oci_result($rssqlclass,"photo");
 }
 header("Content-type: image/jpeg");print $a;`

Comment: yes, but try removing the header() just to check what really is in $a. Comment out header() add print_r($a)

Comment: which one?? I have already tested above code as mentioned and its not working??